# como mover un nodo de un xml usando el mismo documento con elementTree o lxml en anaconda python

Tags: python, anaconda

como puedo mover un nodo completo a cualquier poscicion en el mismo documento xml estoy usando element Tree en el programa anaconda python pero solo e conseguido leer el archivo y reescribirlo pero necesito mover todo el nodo si alguien sabe hacerlo en lxml tambien me podria ayudar muchoo para ser mas claro quisiera que persona 2 se encontrara en la primera poscicion y asi poder mover varios nodos no e encontrado algo claro asta ahora que solucione el problema

```
<Persona2>
    <A11 Nombre="antonio" />
<A22 edad="22" />
<A33 direccion="tepescoloyo" />
<A44 Telefono="25347976" />  
</Persona2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega una estructura mas completa del XML de ejemplo, para ver como y donde esta definido persona1.
me llama la atención como esta definido tu XML, la estructura a mi parecer debería ser :

```
<Personas>
  <Persona>
    <Nombre>antonio</Nombre>
    <Edad>22</Edad>
    <Direccion>tepescoloyo</Direccion>
    <Telefono>25347976</Nombre>
  </Persona>
</Personas>
```